# What does it mean to write a "glowing" letter of recommendation?

Tags: graduate-admissions, recommendation-letter

I'm soon going to apply for admission into a masters program and I will be getting LORs from my place of employment.

I often hear the phrase `glowing letter of recommendation`. What does it mean for a LOR to "glow" and what are the components/features of glowing LOR?

If its possible, can you please share some samples/slices of a glowing LOR?

Comment: Glowing means very positive. But what the letter should actually say depends on what employers in that specific field want to read in a letter, so I'm not sure you'll get very useful answers here.

Comment: "Glowing" is a standard English expression for something that is very positive or full of praise.  You can find it in dictionaries, e.g. [here](https://www.collinsdictionary.com/us/dictionary/english/glowing).

Comment: An example of a glowing letter is here: https://academia.stackexchange.com/q/29642/4484

Answer (score 7):

A "glowing" letter is one that praises the candidate in the highest terms on several criteria: "One of the three best .... I've ever worked with...". The letter will detail both past performance and make positive predictions about the future.

However, it is possible for such a letter to overdo the praise and then be discounted by the reader as shallow.

What you want a letter on your behalf to say is that you are knowledgeable and that you work hard and that you have a lot of ideas and potential. A glowing letter will reinforce those ideas with examples and/or comparisons. In some fields, positive statements about teamwork can also be important. In others, being seen as self-directed is more important.

But it also needs to be realistic. "Candidate calms hurricanes and has the compassion of a saint" is probably too much to believe.